# How to make link of file(cell) in excel if directory of file change by day?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to change path of the link

='C:\2019\jan\01[eg.xlsx]worksheet'!A1

if the path of the file is changed every day and the name of file is same. 
Eg. year is in cell D2, month is in cel D3 and day is in cell D4 so the link should be something like this:

='C:\cell D2\cell D3\cell D4[eg.xlsx]worksheet'!A1

the D2-D4 cell is changing every day automaticly which I have done and it's work.

Comment: Build that path from parts using indirect()

Comment: You should be able to just reference the cells with year, month and day. `="'C:\"&D2&"\"&D3&"\"&D4&"[eg.xlsx]worksheet'!A1"`

Comment: this is not working becouse it not show the value of A1 cell of eg.xlsx file. it show path of file but that is all, and it change &D_& with the value in that cell which is good,

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=HYPERLINK("[C:\"&D2&"\"&E2&"\"&F2&"\"&"eg.xlsx]Sheet1!A1")
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: this is ok when you want a link to file, but it not show the value of cell A1 of the eg.xlsx